# Using operator keyword in a switch statement

Tags: c++, linux

So I am trying to use the "operator" keyword in this switch statement but when I do I get the error "error: expected type-specifier before â:â token operator:"
I am not getting any error for the digit keyword. Any ideas?

```
for (i=0; i < pf.length(); i++)
  {
    int opn1;
    int opn2;
    int result;
    char token = pf[i];
    switch (token)
      {
         digit:
          {
           chast.push(token); break;
          }
         operator:
          {
           opn2 = chast.top();
           chast.pop();
           opn1 = chast.top();
           chast.pop();
           result = evaluate(opn1, token, opn2);
           chast.push(result);
           break;
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I'm trying to use the "dynamite" ingredient in my wedding cake, but when I do, the oven misbehaves. I am not getting any problems for the "wood chips" ingredient.

Comment: @KerrekSB What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I think it's fairly clear he's expecting it to not throw an error.

Comment: @nicomp "Not throw an error" is a long way away from "do something useful", though.

Comment: Your switch statement is quite invalid. You're not specifying any `cases` (did you mean `case digit:`?), but even if you did, what are `digit` and `operator`? Are they consts in your code? Are they imaginary constructs to deduce that `token` might be a `+` symbol vs a `1` digit?

Comment: Re " I am not getting any error for the digit keyword", that's not a keyword.

Comment: @immibis,  Irrelevant but true.

Answer (score 2):

The code as presented is syntactically invalid:

- It lacks the `case` keyword for the `switch` labels.
- It uses the keyword `operator` as a name.

Re

> **”** I am not getting any error for the digit keyword.

… that's not a keyword.

Google C++ keywords. Get yourself [a decent C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn about the basic constructs of the language.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, operator is a keyword used only for operator overloading. Unfortunately, that makes it illegal to use in any other case.

Where is "digit" defined in your code?

Comment: I didnt define it but both show up yellow like all the other reserved words when I use them. Sorry if what I'm asking seems stupid.